# Min(date) in sum case statement

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to write a statement where the settled date is less than the `min(duedate)` but I'm getting this error:

> Msg 130, Level 15, State 1, Line 32
>   Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.

This is the query I'm using - can anyone help please?

```
...
sum(case when 
             cast(l.settleddate AS date) < min(cast(f.datedue as DATE)) 
         then 1 
         else 0
    end) as BeforeFirstDue
```

Comment: It would be better if you included the whole query.

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @myDate AS datetime
SELECT @myDate = min(cast(f.datedue as DATE)) FROM tablef f
SELECT 
    sum(case when cast(l.settleddate AS date) < @myDate
             Then 1 
             else 0      
             end) as BeforeFirstDue
FROM tablel l
```

Comment: use Aggregate function MIN() to get value from a set of data and then use another Aggregate function SUM() to get value base on the MIN() result in  this syntax is not possible

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to give a proper answer without the full query.  So let's pretend that your query looks something like this:

```
SELECT sum(case when 
                  cast(l.settleddate AS date) < min(cast(f.datedue as DATE)) 
                then 1 
                else 0
           end) as BeforeFirstDue
  FROM tableL l
  JOIN tableF f
    ON f.someKey = l.someKey
```

If that's your case, here is one way you can rewrite your query to do what you want:

```
SELECT sum(case when 
                  t.settleddate < t.mindatedue
                then 1 
                else 0
           end) as BeforeFirstDue
  FROM (SELECT cast(l.settleddate AS date) AS settleddate,
               min(cast(f.datedue as DATE)) OVER () AS mindatedue
          FROM tableL l
          JOIN tableF f
            ON f.someKey = l.someKey) t
```

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing your granularity inside your CASE statement. You cannot compare an aggregate with a non aggregate unless they come from two different datasets